# How to get notified about Android appcompat or support library updates?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, dependency-management

I wonder if there is a way to get notified about updates of the Google Android libraries such as `com.android.support:support-v4`, `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` and so on.

I am aware that I could use `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"` with the `+` in my gradle build. But it would be nice to get an eMail or have an RSS Feed with the new releses of all the different android libraries by google. This would help a lot to keep the dependencies up to date and publish a new version of my app to the play store.

**Edit**:
I found this url https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml which is used to update the local m2repo (which includes the above mentioned librarys).

Comment: In Android Studio 1.5 the dependency will be highlighted for the support libraries in your build.gradle. All I did was click alt+enter and I got a pop-up that asked if I wanted to update to the latest version. Same for Google Play Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is interesting and it made me think on how I may address myself the problem to actually find a solution. Here's my thought: I use myself [ifttt](https://ifttt.com) and alike and the missing point is then the monitoring of the xml data. A Google search later, I've just found [this blog post](http://colinschimmelfing.com/blog/automated-monitoring-of-web-pages-using-page2rss-feedly-and-ifttt/) which is a thoroughful description of the steps needed to get notified by mail of a change in a web page. HEY, THAT'S WHAT WE NEED!!!

I've not tested since I need to wait for an actual update but here is the resulting RSS: [page2RSS android addon monitoring](http://page2rss.com/rss/afc9b1ecb8c7006e47d7e236f40f9313)

**Update (May 9):** [page2rss has been shut down on May 1st](https://twitter.com/Page2RSS/status/724382736857714690), as a consequence other services must be used/tested. [Wachete](https://www.wachete.com) seems to provide similar services, but one needs an account.

Comment: awsome solution! hope this works, but we will see if the page gets updated!

Answer (score 4):

A real "push" notification solution would require lots of boring details like setting up xmpp or email accounts. However, this is a very valid question and one I have recently solved not just for appcompat libraries but for all my dependencies.

### gradle-versions-plugin

This [excellent plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) analyzes your depdencies and checks for newer releases. Example console output:

```
$ gradle dependencyUpdates
...
The following dependencies are using the latest milestone version:
 - com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
 - com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
 - com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
 - com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
 - com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1
 - com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1
 - com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.11.3

The following dependencies have later milestone versions:
 - com.android.tools.build:gradle [1.5.0-beta1 -> 2.0.0-alpha1]
 - com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm [7.5.0 -> 8.3.0]
 - com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit [1.9.0 -> 2.0.0-beta2]
 - net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK [3.5.0 -> 3.7.0-beta.2]
 - org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library [1.1 -> 1.4-atlassian-1]
 - org.mockito:mockito-core [1.10.19 -> 2.0.31-beta]
```

You can just run this any time you want to check for newer versions. And since it also supports json output format, if you really wanted to script some kind of notification, you could cronjob it and parse the json output and do whatever you'd like at that point.

Comment: This is an awesome plugin! Thank you for the answer. If running a jenkins or some CI this will help a lot. I will give the bounty to @Renaud because his solution gives the full push without a lot of setup.

Comment: (I am away from a PC to confirm myself). Isn't there a code analysis rule in Android Stuildio ) to check for this as well? I think this is what triggers the highlights in the `build.graddle` file that @Jared Rummler mentions in his comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an RSS or something like that, but you can visit periodically this page:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Or visit the Android Developers Blog (often Ian Lake, a Google Developer Advocate, update it with pertinent posts):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/

Comment: Thanks but I would like to have more like a 'push' - via email or something - then a 'pull' of the infos. Gets kind of boring to check the pages all the time.